# Dart i18n library

Tags: internationalization, dart

I'm trying to use the package [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) but my brain fails to understand ...

Do you have a simple example of how to use it, when we come from [chrome.i18n](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n)?

Comment: Add some more specific details about the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to localize some messages, I think that [l10n](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/l10n) would be nice to you. It generates PO files and use it to translate.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample - https://github.com/dart-lang/sample-polymer-intl

Top-level explanation:
  You write your message initially wrapped in an Intl.message call, which should be in a function that does just that. So, e.g.

```
  hello() => Intl.message("Hello world");
  print(hello());
```

If you run that it will just run without any modification. You can extract out the messages using bin/extract_to_arb.dart, translate them, and run bin/generate_from_arb.dart.

Compared to chrome.i18n:

- You write your message in this wrapped-in-a-function-style and the default locale (let's say English) version just runs.
- Your program doesn't read the JSON files directly, you run a code generator on them and it generates a library per locale.
- You don't use getMessage or anything, it just runs the same way it did before.
- To use messages from a particular locale you initialize the locale (which loads the deferred library) and then set it as the default.
- It generates and consumes ARB files, and the interpretation of messages is like ICU.

Is that what you were looking for?